# Show Flow Document Without Rules

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I want to show a flow document without its defalut rules.

[image]

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer >
        <FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

for more details visit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx